# STM32 call to memcpy causes hardfault (the call to memcpy itself, not the execution of memcpy)

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

**Situation:** I am working with a crypto library called embedded disco, I have a demo working on my PC but when porting it over to the MCU I get a hard fault when executing a library procedure. In the faulting code, the library is trying to simply copy the content of one `strobe_s` struct into another `strobe_s`. This is done twice: once for `s1` and once for `s2`. For `s1`, the library simply assigns the dest. struct to the source struct. For `s2` however, such an assign gave a hard fault. As the Cortex-M ISA requires aligned memory accesses, I reckoned that replacing the assignment with a memcpy should fix the problem. Nevertheless, simply stepping into memcpy using the debugger results in a hard fault! I.e. I have a breakpoint at the line with the memcpy and when stepping inside the fault handler is called! I have used memcpy to fix misaligned memory accesses in other parts of the code just fine...

**MCU:** STM32L552ZET6QU

**Faulting code:**

The code below is my modification of the original library code where the assignment to `*s2` was replaced by a memcpy. The original code from the [library's github](https://github.com/mimoo/disco-c/blob/bbf84d64d7de6956009872caa77bfe7691cd471b/lib/disco_asymmetric.c#L116) was:

```
  // s1 = our current strobe state
  *s1 = ss->strobe;
  if (!half_duplex) {
    // s2 = s1
    *s2 = ss->strobe;
  }
```

My modified version:

```
  // s1 = our current strobe state
  *s1 = ss->strobe;
  if (!half_duplex) {
    // s2 = s1
    // WARNING: The below code will give a HARD FAULT ON THE STM32L552ZE!
    // *s2 = ss->strobe;
    // Fix I tried: Use memcpy instead!
    memcpy((void*) s2, (void*)(&(ss -> strobe)), sizeof(strobe_s));
  }
```

**Parameter values of memcpy:**

Right before the execution of memcpy, the debugger shows me the following values for the variables in question:

```
Expr.   Type                Value
----------------------------------------------------
s1      strobe_s *          0x800c374   
s2      strobe_s *          0x800a497 <_fflush_r+66>    
ss      symmetricState *    0x2002f988  
&s1     strobe_s **         0x2002f690  
&s2     strobe_s **         0x2002f68c  
&ss     symmetricState **   0x2002f694
```

**Typedefs:**

```
typedef struct symmetricState_ {
  strobe_s strobe;
  bool isKeyed;
} symmetricState;

/** Keccak's domain: 25 words of size b/25, or b/8 bytes. */
typedef union {
  kword_t w[25];
  uint8_t b[25 * sizeof(kword_t) / sizeof(uint8_t)];
} kdomain_s;

/** The main strobe state object. */
typedef struct strobe_s_ {
  kdomain_s state;
  uint8_t position;
  uint8_t pos_begin;
  uint8_t flags;
  uint8_t initiator;
  uint8_t initialized;  // strobe is initialized if this value is set to 111.
                        // This is because we cannot assume that a boolean would
                        // be set to false initially (C stuff). A uint8_t is a
                        // short value but here we do not care about security
                        // much, rather catching bugs early in a development
                        // environement.
} strobe_s;
```

**Questions:**

1. How is it possible that just the *call* to memcpy without actually executing a single instruction within memcpy gives a hard fault?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the `void*` casts, they are unnecessary and may supress helpful warnings.

Comment: see what has caused the hard fault. You need to read regiters and values from the stack. Or download atollic studio or CubeMxIDE  as they have a very handy plugging called nomen omen faultAnalyzer

Comment: The code on github has the code in question preceded by an asserts that neither `s1` nor `s2` are `NULL` - rather inexplicably there is no check that `ss` is not `NULL`.  I'd also recommend using `sizeof(*s2)` rather then `sizeof(strobe_s)` - just a far safer habit.

Comment: @Clifford I removed the castings, no further warnings appeared. The code on github indeed has the asserts and I also have them in my code. I just didn't carry them over into the question to keep the code block small. The asserts are satisfied and `ss` is non-NULL, `ss == 0x2000f988`.

Comment: @iMrFelix : I was not expecting any of that to fix it - otherwise I'd have posted an answer.  Just observations and good practice.  Note that unless you explicitly enable selective exception handling, any exception is transmuted to a hard fault.  Stepping _into_ the functional call at the assembly instruction level, may help.  It may be the evaluation of the arguments that is failing before the call is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
s2      strobe_s *          0x800a497 <_fflush_r+66>
```

`s2`is a flash (read-only) address.  Copying to read-only memory is both semantically erroneous and may trigger an MPU fault if the region were set to read-only.

It is not clear to me how the original code worked or indeed how:

```
 *s1 = ss->strobe;
```

is not causing a problem too however.  Certainly it won't work as intended even if there were no exception.

Comment: I indeed noticed that while updating the question and it turns out that higher up in the calling hierarchy an erroneous parameter was passed (a strobe_s instead of a ptr. to a strobe_s). As that error happened rather far away from where the fault occurred, I missed it!

Comment: @iMrFelix it would be interesting to see that call. The compiler should have caught that unless you foiled it by an Ill-advised cast. That is why I advised against the unnecessary cast in this case - it tells the compiler _"don't complain about this, I know what I an doing"_ ... except if course when you don't. Suppressing compiler warnings or errors through a cast should be a last resort, not habitual

Comment: I can add the erroneous code in a further question edit. The reason I always cast is that e.g. when using HAL_UART_Transmit(...) with a char* instead of a uint8_t* as payload, I happen to always get signedness warnings.

Comment: @iMrFelix It is perhaps not relevant, just my curiosity.  You never need to cast to void*; that is the purpose of void*.  The STM32 HAL interface sucks, but habitually casting everything is not the solution.  Cast only what you need to cast, and prefer type agreement otherwise.  Otherwise as you have found you end up with hard to fathom runtime errors where you could have had a more straightforward build error.  If you cast only when the compiler requires it rather than by habit, you can review each cast as a deviation as you should, rather than globally hiding errors.

Comment: All of the handshaking logic of the disco library is contained in a custom function `server_disco_connect(c_write, c_read)`, where `c_write`, `c_read` _should_ be pointers to strobe states. I erroneously called `disco_connect` with the structs directly. Why the compiler didn't complain I can't say, but it certainly didn't (I didn't even cast them!).

In case you are up for a challenge, I just posted a new issue for which I would really appreciate some help! :)

Comment: @iMrFelix I would but my heart sinks everytime I see that `HAL_UART` turd pile.

Comment: Haha well I feel you... Do you usually just use your own custom implementation or how else do you interact with UART on STM32s?